# UV texture different in render

Tags: uv

I applied an image texture on a shape and UV mapped it. It looks good on preview mode but when I render the image, then the texture does not look good anymore...
I don't really what is happening since my texture coordinate is set to UV
Any thought?
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: If you're using a subdivision surface modifier, make sure to set the render levels at the same value as viewport levels. Also, you may have an hidden object that's not disabled for rendering

Comment: I can see some digits of the ruler there, so I think what you have there is 2 objects, one perhaps hidden in the viewport but it still renders. Either disable its rendering in the outliner or unhide and move/delete it in the viewport.

Comment: In the attached .blend file the textures aren't packed, but indeed pressing Alt+H reveals duplicates.

Comment: You are right... There were hidden objects not disabled for rendering, classic beginner mistake haha! Thank you all!